# Exoplayer-2 Hls Streaming Issue

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am developing an android app which has an activity with exoplayer that plays hls media. I am facing an issue which is strange to me. The player activity when called as launcher activity runs fine but when I call it from other activities, it stops buffering right after 12 seconds. Checking log cat gave me error which has something to do with playlist. Below is my sample code of exoplayer activity. If this activity is called as launcher main activity, it runs absolutely fine. Is there any difference between running activity as launcher and launching activity from other intent? Please help me with this issue. My log cat error:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.                                                                 

com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistTracker$PlaylistStuckException
                                                                      at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistTracker$MediaPlaylistBundle.processLoadedPlaylist(HlsPlaylistTracker.java:598)
                                                                      at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistTracker$MediaPlaylistBundle.onLoadCompleted(HlsPlaylistTracker.java:539)
                                                                      at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistTracker$MediaPlaylistBundle.onLoadCompleted(HlsPlaylistTracker.java:472)
                                                                      at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.handleMessage(Loader.java:383)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Exoplayer Activity:

```
    private void initializePlayer() {
    final SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerVoiw;
    Uri mp4VideoUri;
    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
    bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
    simpleExoPlayerVoiw = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);

   /* player.release();
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);*/
    simpleExoPlayerVoiw.setUseController(true);
    simpleExoPlayerVoiw.requestFocus();
    simpleExoPlayerVoiw.setPlayer(player);



    mp4VideoUri = Uri.parse("http://125.17.129.4/wh7f454c46tw2717373403_526904823/PLTV/88888888/224/3221225827/01.m3u8"); //Radnom 540p indian channel
    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeterA = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "cricflame"),(TransferListener<? super DataSource>) bandwidthMeterA);

    MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(mp4VideoUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
    final LoopingMediaSource loopingMediaSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource);
    player.prepare(loopingMediaSource);

    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    player.release();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    initializePlayer();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to not use `LoopingMediaSource`? Try to use `HlsMediaSource` directly. It looks like the issue could be related to live stream.

Comment: Have you found the answer for this @Tirtha. I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I used it 2 years ago, I cannot remember everything how I solved it, however I used different source rather than loopingmediasource. Loopingmediasource wasn't performing properly in non launcher activities.